# Como ordenar alfabéticamente una columna concatenada

Tags: powerbi

Quisiera ordenar alfabéticamente una columna que se concatenada con otra, es decir, estoy en la creación de una columna personalizada en la que estoy concatenando dos columnas.

La formula de columna personalizada que estoy usando es la siguiente:

```
= [IdCliente] & " - " & [NombreCliente]
```

La columna que me interesa ordenar alfabéticamente es `[NombreCliente]`

Intente ordenar la columna `[NombreCliente]` haciendo uso de la función `Order.Ascending` de la siguiente manera:

```
= [IdCliente] & " - " & Order.Ascending [NombreCliente]
```

Pero esto lo me genera un error indicándome lo siguiente:

```
 Expression.Error: No se puede aplicar el acceso de campo al tipo Number.
Detalles:
    Value=0
    Key=NombreCliente
```

Alguna sugerencia para ordenar correctamente mi columna en orden alfabético.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no te he entendido mal, creo que podrías conseguir lo que necesitas ordenando tu columna concatenada (llamémosla "Id-Nombre") por la columna "NombreCliente".

De esta forma, cuando ordenes por "Id-Nombre" se hará en base a "NombreCliente" y no por "IdCliente" ya que es el primero en la concatenación.

Te quedaría el siguiente orden:

[image: Clientes ordenados]

Como ves el orden de la columna "Id-Nombre" es alfabético en lugar de ser numérico por el Id.

Para hacer esto tienes que seleccionar tu columna en la que concatenas el Id y el Nombre y seleccionar en la sección "Herramientas de columnas" el botón "Ordenar por columna", en el que seleccionarías la columna "NombreCliente":

[image: Herramientas de columna - Ordenar por columna]

Espero que esto te sirva de ayuda.